# Parse-JSON is XML case sensitive

Tags: xsd, case-sensitive, tibco, tibco-business-works

An API call returns a JSON string, to convert the JSON string to XML we need to use ParseJson Activity, the parser deals with the XML tags as case sensitive. How can I make the parsing process ignore the case sensitivity of the XML tags.

I have tried to add a substitution group in the XSD on the element level, however, Tibco BW prevents me from doing this on the element level.

Any help?

Comment: Normalize your content before or after to ensure that the JSON properties or XML Elements have the expected case.

Answer (score 0):

While both XML and JSON are case sensitive the BusinessWorks behavior is consistent.

To manage your requirement I can think of two approaches :

.1 Create a new XSD that will be identical to your current XSD but with all element names changed to be in small caps.
Then parse your JSON string using this new XSD and map the created XML structure to a structure defined with the original XSD. If you are using BusinessWorks 6.7 or 6.8 this can be done using the new SmartMapper capabilities.

.2 Before parsing the JSON string change it to be all in small ou capital caps (depending how your XSD is defined). This can be done using the XPATH translate function. A side effect is that strings present in the JSON message would also be changed (I mean the message content would be changed).